# How to join tables in Spring Data Reactive to query two tables in a Repository interface?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am building a Spring Webflux application using Spring Data Reactive.

I have the following `Role` Entity:

```
 */
public class Role implements Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    @Transient
    private boolean isNew;
```

And this is the `RoleOrganization` entity:

```
public class RoleOrganization implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private UUID roleId;  //points to Role.id
    private UUID organizationId;
```

I am trying to find all the roles that matches by `RoleOrganization.organizationId` and `Role.name` columns using the following query:

```
    @Query("select r.* from Role r inner join  RoleOrganization ro " +
            "on r.id=ro.organizationId and ro.organizationId =:id  and r.name =:name")
    Flux<Role> findByOrganizationIdAndName(@Param("id") UUID id, @Param("name") String name);
```

I am getting the following error on this query execution:

````
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 
org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: executeMany; 
bad SQL grammar [select r.* from Role r inner join  RoleOrganization ro on 
r.id=ro.organizationId and ro.organizationId =$1  and r.name =$2]```
````

It seems like I can't join two tables in a query.

Comment: "select r.*" Is SQL notation - how is this even executing without you marking the query as being a native query? (nativeQuery = true) Are you maybe using JPQL  "select r from Role r" and just cut and paste it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
  @Query("select r from Role r join RoleOrganization ro on r.id=ro.organizationId " +
            "where ro.organizationId =:id  and r.name =:name")
    Flux<Role> findByOrganizationIdAndName(@Param("id") UUID id, @Param("name") String name);
```

or no need to join:

```
  @Query("select r from Role where r.organizationRole.organizationId =:id and r.name =:name")
    Flux<Role> findByOrganizationIdAndName(@Param("id") UUID id, @Param("name") String name);
```

as it should create the join internally

NB: I assumed that the Role class has a field of type RoleOrganization:

```
public class Role {

@OneToOne
private RoleOrganization roleOrganization;
}
```

Comment: I tried both and it doesn't work.  I updated my answer to show the properties of each entity.  Role doesn't have organizationId.

Comment: Maybe show the error you get if you added a OneToOne and what exactly isn't working in the queries you tried using that relationship.